# What does "expanding the surface area of the library" mean?

Tags: swift

I am reading [Swift Evolution proposal 244 (Opaque Result Types)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md#introduction) and don't understand what the following means:

> "... expanding the surface area of the library"
>
> The underlying concrete type is hidden, and can even change from one
> version of the library to the next without breaking those clients,
> because the underlying type identity is never exposed to clients.
> Unlike an existential, though, clients still have access to the type
> identity. This allows the library to provide a
> potentially-more-efficient design that leverages Swift's type system,
> without ***expanding the surface area of the library*** or making
> implementors of the library's protocols rely on exposing verbose
> implementation types.

Source: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md#introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "surface area" of a library is basically the list of things that are exposed to the user. This quote is saying that this proposal allows substantial internal changes to a library without it having a large effect on the users of the library.